# Initialize a JavaScript/TypeScript object with computed property names from enum/array values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to initialize a JavaScript/TypeScript object with computed property names from an enum (or, from the values of an array).  I figured out how to create the computed properties in a loop, but was hoping there might be some clever initilizer syntax to do it all in one go.

Example: Given a TypeScript enum like:

```
 enum Amenities { FreeWeights = "Free Weights", CardioMachines = "Cardio Machines", ... };
```

I'm trying to create an object like:

```
 { ['Cardio Machines'] : Boolean,
   ['Free Weights'] : Boolean}
```

I can do this in a loop (and using a third-party library to transform the TS enum values into an array):

```
 import { $enum } from "ts-enum-util";
 
 let amenitiesObj : any = {};
 $enum(Amenities).getValues().forEach(element => { amenitiesObj[element] = Boolean; });
```

However, I feel like there's probably a sytax that allows this to be done directly in the initializer.  I'm relatively new to both TypeScript and ES6, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*I feel like there's probably a sytax that allows this to be done directly in the initializer*" there isn't. You cannot have an object literal with variable amount of properties *unless* you're spreading an existing object into it. But you need to create *that* object somehow without using an object literal. It's t̶u̶r̶t̶l̶e̶s̶ object literals all the way down. Unless you generate the object via another means.

Comment: There is - please see accepted answer.

Comment: I can see it's not done in an object initialiser. So, I don't see how this contradicts me saying you cannot do it in an object initialiser.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I used the wrong term then - in any case, the answer was pretty much exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use computed properties manually:

```
const obj1 = { [Amenities.FreeWeights]: true, [Amenities.CardioMachines]: true };
```

Or use `Object.values()` on the enum, map the keys to `[key, value]` pairs, and convert to an object with `Object.fromEntries()` (requires `lib: es2019` or later in tsconfig):

```
const obj2 = Object.fromEntries(Object.values(Amenities).map(k => [k, true]));
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/AQUwdgrgtsCCXgJYBdEgM7AN7AGICcQQB1ERAcwAtlMBeYAIgKOFIuvQYBpgBhAQ3wATRAHsAsvwDGlRGAzB6DAcLHBJMuRgbAAvgG4AUIeBTRYdMmCiARgCsAjIuzAA2vCSoMAOmYkyVDQAugBcwMj4ECA87ghgKGjo3ioiEtKy8uih4ZEgekYmZhZWtnYATM4A8vYgUsjeAGb4olAAomARiQAU1Xa19QBu-AA2UehdHvFe6ACU3lD8AA5dANaKAHxuKzwRUUEzMwVF6KLDIN7DouRdpQ6Hxsen55fXpWWHQA)